# Export Excel to SQL - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, webforms

I am following this tutorial online to transfer information from the SQL Database to an Excel Sheet. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/export-sql-data-to-excel-using-Asp-Net/

At the moment I already have data in an SQL database so am using step 4 onwards. On the Graph.aspx file I have created a button

```
<asp:Button ID ="btnSQLToExcel" runat ="server" Text ="Download SQL To Excel" OnClick="btnLoad_Click" />
```

Then in the Graph.aspx.cs file I have the following methods when the button is clicked:

```
protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(GridView1.Visible)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = GridViewToExcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
            GridView1.RenderControl(hTextWriter);
            Response.Write(sWriter.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }
```

If I take out the last method it shows the error he describes on his website *'Control 'GridView1' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server'*. But by adding the second method this was supposed to handle this but instead I get the following error.

An exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code.

additional information: RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();

I'm way out of my depth on this one so if anyone could let me know what I am doing wrong, or even a better way to convert sql to excel in web forms it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the issue was. But when I created the SQL Grid View via the visual studio tools it didn't work. When I manually created the grid view in C# it now works. If someone can tell me what it is that is the difference then that would be helpful.